# How we can get nvarchar column value from SQL Server in talend

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, etl, talend, talend-mdm

I'm trying to get nvarchar value in Talend from SQL Server but am not able to get it. Attached is the snapshot for these [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E7xv2.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V6zop.png)

In SQL Server I have value as **testing/АКМЛЛИАА УВЛАЛИУЛЛУЛИНУА_7373992343/** but when I'm trying to get in Talend then I'm getting as **testing/???????? ???????????????_7373992343/**

.................................................................................;

Comment: Please add more detail to your question it's helpful to mention the input componants your using, a screenshot of the job if possible and if you've done any research.